# why does openssl_public_encrypt not accept even modulos for unpadded RSA?

Tags: c, openssl, php-openssl, php-internals

Unpadded RSA is basically modular exponentiation. So it seems like `openssl_public_encrypt($plaintext, $result, "$rsa", OPENSSL_NO_PADDING)` ought to be a good way to do fast modular exponentiation (where `$rsa` contained the modulus and the exponent and `$plaintext` was the number you wanted to do the modular exponentiation on). Only problem: it doesn't work consistently. In particular, when the modulo is even, I get the following error:

```
failure: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

So I thought I'd look into the code to figure out why.

Here's what PHP does for `openssl_public_encrypt` ([openssl.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/openssl/openssl.c)):

```
        successful = (RSA_public_encrypt((int)data_len,
                    (unsigned char *)data,
                    (unsigned char *)ZSTR_VAL(cryptedbuf),
                    EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA(pkey),
                    (int)padding) == cryptedlen);
```

Here's what OpenSSL does for `RSA_public_encrypt` ([rsa_crpt.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/rsa/rsa_crpt.c)):

```
int RSA_public_encrypt(int flen, const unsigned char *from, unsigned char *to,
                       RSA *rsa, int padding)
{
    return (rsa->meth->rsa_pub_enc(flen, from, to, rsa, padding));
}
```

From here it's not clear to me what's happening. Where is `rsa->meth_rsa_pub_enc` defined? Maybe it corresponds to something in the engines subdirectory of the OpenSSL repo?:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/master/engines

edit: an RSA key with an even (invalid) modulo:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I also tried the key in an alt format:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----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==
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Neither work.

Comment: If you're looking to do modular exponentiation, why not just use one of the many libraries that do just that? There's a mod_exp in openssl as well, although I don't know if it's accessible in the PHP bindings.

Comment: User land PHP libraries tend to be a lot slower than native C. `gmp_powm` is great if GMP is available but it's not always available. And `bcpowmod` is awful. You can implement a faster mod_exp in PHP than `bcpowmod` provides per the out of date http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/math/intro.html . Outside of gmp or bcmath what other alternatives exist? http://pecl.php.net/package/big_int that is installed on exactly zero servers, probably doesn't work on PHP 7 and hasn't been updated in over a decade?

Comment: Well, that's a different question then, you're asking this because you can't install dependencies because you have no control of the server? It seems like a pretty narrow edge-case. If you do want do dig around what is where in OpenSSL, easiest thing is to load the source in a C-capable IDE so you can easily navigate around. Netbeans is a free option.

Comment: @pvg - I'm asking as an intellectual curiosity. Not every question has to have a practical application lol

Comment: You're likely going to have to dig around the source to see what happens. One possibility is some kind of parameter sanity checking - an even n is obviously catastrophically bad for the purposes of RSA.

Comment: *`PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line`* likely means your public key is not PEM encoded, or there's a problem with the PEM encoding. `cat` the public key and add it to the question. Some libraries don't handle line endings well. [PEM specifies `CRLF` pair as the line ending](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1421) (see Section 9. Descriptive Grammar), so be sure they are present.

Comment: @jww - I'm pretty sure the *format* of the keys isn't the problem. I posted my keys. They have an even modulo so they are not suitable for actual RSA.

Comment: The C code you posted above only does the RSA_public_encrypt() call itself. There are other routines that handle decoding the RSA key from the PEM file, which presumably you have omitted. The "no start line" error comes from the OpenSSL PEM handling code, so it's a bit difficult to say why you get that error without seeing what the PHP PEM code is doing.

Comment: rsa_pub_enc() is a function pointer. What this points can be changed at runtime but most likely you are using the default implementation. In OpenSSL 1.0.2 the default is RSA_eay_public_encrypt() defined in the file crypto/rsa/rsa_eay.c. In OpenSSL 1.1.0 the default is rsa_ossl_public_encrypt() defined in the file crypto/rsa/rsa_ossl.c

Comment: @MattCaswell - it looks like it's doing `PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY` and then `EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA`. It is not immediately obvious to me, tho, where `PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY` is defined. I'm not seeing it in https://github.com/openssl/openssl/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY&type= .

Comment: PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY is defined via a macro here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0-stable/crypto/pem/pem_all.c#L181 It's basically a thin wrapper around the PEM_ASN1_read_bio() function defined here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0-stable/crypto/pem/pem_oth.c#L20